# How to make TextBlock editable in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, textblock

I would like to make TextBox Editable, how to do it?  Exacly, when the user taps it there is a keyboard letting him insert a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextBlock` or `TextBox`?  TextBlock is not editable - it's akin to a Label control.  If you an editable text control, use the `TextBox`.

Comment: I have found a way to make a TextBlock editable, but it did not work for me. Used TextBox.

Comment: @RobertKilar You managed to edit a TextBlock instance?  Could you share how?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something very simple.
You need to create both a TextBlock and a TextBox. 
You'll have to control their visibility from code.
You'll have to bind (two way) the text property of the TextBox to the TextBlock in xaml.
Once the textBlock is clicked for edit, you hide it from code, make the TextBox visible. The texts in the textBlock will be there since you have binded. 
Edit your text and maybe focus away or have an interaction to run an event that can Collapse the TextBox and show the TextBlock again. Now with the edited text since its Binded.
Do you need a code for this?